# How To Get Single Column Result From SqlServer Query Using Group By

Tags: sql-server

I have two classic tables (OK, not my real problem). Orders and OrderItems.  I want to using a single statement to delete all Orders that have no OrderItems.  I can get the list of Orders I want to delete with a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),OrderId
FROM OrderItems
GROUP BY OrderId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

and what I want to do is something like:

```
DELETE FROM Orders WHERE Id NOT IN (....)
```

Where "...." is my SELECT above. The select is giving me two columns and I really don't want the second column, just the first.

I feel like there is some kind of self join, or something like that I can use but I'm read only when it comes to that.

Comment: Remove the `COUNT(*)` from the `SELECT` clause, leave the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE from Orders Where Id NOT IN (SELECT OrderId
FROM OrderItems
GROUP BY OrderId 
HAVING COUNT(*) >0);
```

Comment: thanks.  not sure why I thought I had to have the count(*) in there.